# Customizing Excel 2010 chart label placement using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-2010

I need to customize the placement of a vertical axis label on a horizontal stacked bar chart in Excel. Currently I can only place the axis label outside of the chart, but I need to show each label inside the chart - to the left or right of the bar it is associated with (depending on orientation).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add a text box that references the cells that contain the title values. This is much easier than customizing the chart titles themselves.